# No shadows or light in image of camera sensor and low fps in gazebo

Tags: gazebo-11

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I wanted to display an office in gazebo 11.
I added some light to make it look better, but so far it seems like the light does not affect the camera sensor.

[image: image description]

Also my fps in the editor is very low (lower than 1 fps).

[image: image description]

Does anyone know what could cause that or how I can add shadow display to the camera sensor and increase the fps in the editor?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/26406/no-shadows-or-light-in-image-of-camera-sensor-and-low-fps-in-gazebo/) by [Zeckurbo](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/36410/zeckurbo/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 64 on 2021-01-13

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Zeckurbo](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/36410/zeckurbo/) on 2021-01-14**:
As it seems the problem of the low fps was because of my virtual machine. I tried a real linux and now it works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Does your simulation has a depth camera included? I had similar problem before that the depth camera disabled the lighting in RGB camera.

If this is the case, I solved it by setting `<always_on>false</always_on>` to the depth camera. Then after you start the simulation, enable the camera (by the Topic Visualization, or a sensor plugin).

For the FPS, there are quite a few factors: the size, number, and complexity of the environment meshes; your GPU sensors' resolutions (cameras, lidars); the lights.

---

Originally posted by [Veerachart](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/39778/veerachart/) with karma: 226 on 2021-01-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0